# CrossPlatformInput Prefabs - Button handler to move?

Tags: unity, c#

I am currently trying to put two buttons on my UI that move a character left and right if touched down (Held). I would like to use the cross platform input, and would like the buttons to change the value of the Horizontal axis as my "A" and "D" keys would...

[image]

And my code for moving my character is as follows:

```
private void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundChecker.position, .15f, groundLayer);


        float move = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
        playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(move, playerRB.velocity.y);




    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to use the OnDrag(PointerEventData data) event to move the character?

Comment: No I want the buttons to link to the Input Horizontal Axis like the A and D keys do when building for standalone

Answer (score 1):

Try to check few things:

1) Canvas (Root) with buttons must have own higher order layer (sorting layers)
2) Buttons must have Z axis enough close to the camera 
3) In Event trigger you should:

- use trigger Pointer Down and ButtonHandler.SetAxisNegativeState (for the left)
- use trigger Pointer UP and ButtonHandler.SetAxisNeutralState (for the left)
- use trigger Pointer Down and ButtonHandler.SetAxisPositiveState (for the right)
- use trigger Pointer Up and ButtonHandler.SetAxisNeutralState (for the right)

4) Maybe you will need add a Graphic Raycaster for parent (of buttons) canvas

I had same issue today and I think it is also in your case, buttons was just un-clickable.

Cheers